# Nodejs cannot get /login

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express, npm

Hi i am following peepcode nodejs screencast, now i have an issues of rendering the login form. My code are as follow:

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
require('coffee-script');
var express = require('express')


  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

require('./apps/authentication/routes');

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and my i have a routes within authentication folder. The code as follow:

routes.coffee

```
routes = (app) ->

  app.get '/login', (req,res) ->
    res.render "views/login", 
      title: 'Login'
      stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```

The coffee script indentation all works fine, but i have an error when i navigate `localhost:3000/login` on browser. The error it display are `Cannot GET /login`. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.js, change this line:

```
require('./apps/authentication/routes');
```

to this:

```
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);
```

What is happening is that in routes.coffee, you're exporting a function that takes a single arg, 'app', and then sets up the route on your app object. You need to call it passing app as the argument.